# Counting unvisited nodes at distance n for every node in graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

For each point in a large graph I am trying to create a list that contains the number of unvisited nodes at distance `n` from the starting node. An example output is:
`[1,3,6]`
which means that at distance 0 there is the starting node itself, at distance 1 there are 3 new (unexplored) nodes, etc.

If you have only one starting point, this is fairly easy: you just augment a shell counter on top of a breadth-first search. The problem starts when I have to do this for every node in my graph. Because my graph is large (> 100000 nodes), it becomes rather slow to do the above routine for every point.

My first attempt to optimize this was to check if the list at node `a` could be constructed from the lists of all the neighbours of `a`, but so far I've had no luck, partly due to cycles in the graph. I am hoping that some of you may have some nice ideas, maybe involving some additional information I can cache.

My question: is there a way to optimize such a search if you know that you will have to do it for **every** node?

Comment: The [all shortest paths problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) is basically what you seek after grouping by distance and counting, and you probably can't really do much better than O(|V|^3).

Comment: My breadth-first search is O(|E|), which is equal to O(|V|) in my case. I have to do it for every node, so my current complexity is O(|V|²). I am now using parallel computing to speed up the process, but other suggestions are most welcome!

Comment: It should still be O(|V|*|E|), which is O(|V|^3) in the worst case. However, if you are saying that |V| is close to |E|, then there probably isn't much more than you can do considering there are O(|V|^2) possible combinations of vertices for which you would need to list shortest paths for. Although, if most vertices have degree 2 or less, then it may be practical to simply list the longest paths (or sufficiently long ones), and extract the shortest paths from them.

Comment: why do you call them unvisited. if i understood you want to know, given a node, how many nodes are at distance D, right?

Comment: Are you okay getting approximate values, or do you need to get exact values back?

Comment: is the graph simple? say from node A to node B there is two path with distance 1 and 3, what should we do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems unlikely that there is a solution in less than `O(n*|V|^2)`, so here is an approach in Python that seems not too terrible.

```
# some basic topologies
def lineE(N): 
  return(set((i,i+1) for i in range(N-1)))

def ringE(N):
  return(lineE(N).union([(0,N-1)]))

def fullE(N):
  return(set([(i,j) for i in range(N) for j in range(i)]))

# propagate visitors from x to y
def propagate(V, curr, x, y, d):
  nexty = set()
  for cx in curr[x]:
    if not cx in V[y]["seen"]:
      V[y]["seen"].add(cx)
      V[y]["foaf"][d] = V[y]["foaf"].get(d,0) + 1
      nexty.add(cx)
  return(nexty)

# run for D iterations
def mingle(N, E, D):
  V = dict((i, {"seen":set([i]), "foaf":{0:1}}) for i in range(N))
  curr = dict((i, set([i])) for i in range(N))
  for d in range(1, min(D+1, N)):
    next = dict((i, set()) for i in range(N))
    for (h, t) in E:
      next[t] = next[t].union(propagate(V, curr, h, t, d))
      next[h] = next[h].union(propagate(V, curr, t, h, d))
    curr = next
  return(V)
```

Trying it out with 10 nodes and distance 3,

```
N=10
D=3
for (topology, E) in [("line", lineE(N)), ("ring", ringE(N)), ("full", fullE(N))]:
  V = mingle(N, E, D)
  print "\n", topology
  for v in V:
    print v, V[v]["foaf"]
```

we get

```
line
0 {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1}
1 {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1}
2 {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1}
3 {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2}
4 {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2}
5 {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2}
6 {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2}
7 {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1}
8 {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1}
9 {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1}

ring
0 {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2}
1 {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2}
2 {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2}
3 {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2}
4 {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2}
5 {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2}
6 {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2}
7 {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2}
8 {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2}
9 {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2}

full
0 {0: 1, 1: 9}
1 {0: 1, 1: 9}
2 {0: 1, 1: 9}
3 {0: 1, 1: 9}
4 {0: 1, 1: 9}
5 {0: 1, 1: 9}
6 {0: 1, 1: 9}
7 {0: 1, 1: 9}
8 {0: 1, 1: 9}
9 {0: 1, 1: 9}
```

which seems correct. Also, running the simple topologies for distance 100 with 100000 nodes takes about a minute on my laptop. Of course if you have a dense graph (like `fullE`) this will blow up.

```
N=100000
D=100
for (topology, E) in [("line", lineE(N)), ("ring", ringE(N))]:
  V = mingle(N, E, D)
```